# Configuring a JNDI resource SQL in Jetty

Tags: jdbc, jetty, jndi

I am having a lot of difficulty configuring a JNDI Resource in Jetty. I've gotten this to work in a Tomcat easily using context.xml and the Resource node. Attempts have been made to specify the resource in Jetty in both the jetty-env.xml and their version of a context.xml file but I end up getting the same exception. Here is the context.xml version of the resource definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

    <New id="DSTest" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg></Arg>
        <Arg>jdbc/SQLDB</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver">
                <Set name="serverName">SQLDB.domain.com</Set>
                <Set name="portNumber">1433</Set>
                <Set name="databaseName">DBName</Set>
                <Set name="userName">UName</Set>
                <Set name="password">PWord</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

The exception being given when I try to start JNDI is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.setServerName(class java.lang.String)
2013-02-01 16:57:39.061:WARN:oejd.DeploymentManager:Unable to reach node goal: started
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.setServerName(class java.lang.String)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.set(XmlConfiguration.java:585)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.itemValue(XmlConfiguration.java:1132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.value(XmlConfiguration.java:1035)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:783)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:398)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:302)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ContextProvider.createContextHandler(ContextProvider.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.App.getContextHandler(App.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardDeployer.processBinding(StandardDeployer.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:494)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:56)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:337)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:555)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:277)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1265)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1188)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:468)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:616)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:92)
```

This exception seems counter intuitive because I can see in the [Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988.aspx) that serverName is a listed as a valid property.

Also, I've run the below command to verify that all expected jar files seem to be included. Specifically those for jndi and sqljdbc.

```
java -jar start.jar --list-options
```

Below are links to tutorials and documentation I have used to get where I am.

```
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/JNDI

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jndi-datasource-examples.html

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jndi.html#configuring-env-entries
```

Any insight the community has would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You must follow these instructions for [Jetty7](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JNDI_Datasource).
For older [Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/DataSource+Examples).

I see that you are trying to use Sql Server, so, you need to use **net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource** as shown in the sample:

```
<New id="DSTest" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
     <Arg></Arg>
     <Arg>jdbc/DSTest</Arg>
     <Arg>
        <New class="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource">
           <Set name="User">user</Set>
           <Set name="Password">pass</Set>
           <Set name="DatabaseName">dbname</Set>
           <Set name="ServerName">localhost</Set>
           <Set name="PortNumber">1433</Set>
        </New>
     </Arg>
    </New>
```

Also, add to **[jetty_home]/lib/ext** the required library [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) or using Maven: [Maven dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds/1.2):

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not with `serverName` method. Method is not there. Neither `portNumber`, etc. on. You cannot use the driver directly.

If you take a look to the jetty [doc](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JNDI_Datasource#SQL_Server_2000), it suggests an alternative for Non-pooling DataSources. But problably you want a pool. So, this [config](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JNDI_Datasource#dbcp).

```
<New class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <Set name="driverClassName">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</Set>
    <Set name="url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<host>:<port>/<database_name></Set>
    <Set name="username">jdbc.user</Set>
    <Set name="password">jdbc.pass</Set>
</New>
```

**Edited**

Regarding your new problem. Not sure what it happening. It looks like jetty is facing problems creating the [temporary directory](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Temporary+Directories). According with the [doc](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin), for Maven plugin the the temporary directory is `${basedir}/target`. Review your jetty maven plugin configuration checking if temporal director is right and if jetty has permissions for that directory.

Comment: Following these instructions I am now getting a null pointer exception when trying to startup the server. This is after downloading jars of commons-dbcp and commons-pool. Stack trace is as follows:

`INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added: C:\jetty-hightide-8.1.7.v20120910\contexts\verivo-env.xml
2013-02-04 10:09:26.186:WARN:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Can't generate resourceBase as part of webapp tmp dir name
java.lang.NullPointerException
...
WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,null}
java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: I have edited my answer, but not clear where the problem is. Take I look to your configuration.